# Can I change permissions for a category in Joomla 2.5 without corrupting asset table?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Can I change work around the Admin Console, and changed the permissions directly in the DB, without corrupting Joomla'a Asset Table?

We are using Joomla 2.5 for a unique application where we had to create thousands of categories. The only issue is that we cannot change the permissions of a particular category using the Admin Console because it times out. We just want to change the permission of Edit from "Inherited" to "Allowed".

The category we are changing the permissions on is not a parent of any other category.

This is not a common task.

Comment: Remember too that permissions are inherited so that means even with thousands of categories if you put them all under one super category you can change the permission in just the super category. In other words, use inheritance but differently.  You shouldn't be timing out though.  You could look at writing a very specific command line application to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to temporarily increase the execution time in your php.ini file. but still if you want to go ahead and make the changes than it wont corrupt the database unless you commit a blunder.
If the permissions for Create Delete Edit etc are inherited then the values in the rules field will look like this

```
{"core.create":[],"core.delete":[],"core.edit":[],"core.edit.state":[],"core.edit.own":[]}
```

And once you make the edit from inherited to Allowed it becomes

```
{"core.create":[],"core.delete":[],"core.edit":{"1":1},"core.edit.state":[],"core.edit.own":[]}
```

So core.edit has an array with key 1 and value 1. You can change similarly for others but be careful changing database directly. Remember key one is for Public permission. Similarly if you need to change for manager it becomes

```
{"core.create":[],"core.delete":[],"core.edit":{"1":1,"6":1},"core.edit.state":[],"core.edit.own":[]}
```

You can see a key 6 is added with value 1 which means the Manager has rights to edit.Key 1 and 6 are group ids of public and Manager respectively. You can get the group ID's if you go to Users->Groups. Right side id will be displayed for each individual group. So suppose you want edit functionality for publisher which is having group id 5 then the rules column will be like this

```
 {"core.create":[],"core.delete":[],"core.edit":{"1":1,"6":1,"5":1},"core.edit.state":[],"core.edit.own":[]}
```

Comment: Thank you.  But I just want to be clear, if I change the values here directly, it will not corrupt the asset table?

Comment: It wont corrupt unless you commit a blunder but I suggest first take a complete backup of your database so that you can recover in case of mishap.

Comment: Thanks!  When you open up the categories in Joomla Admin, it has an inefficient way of loading every permission for every category.  That is why increasing the timeout is not going to work (it might be hours).  I don't know that I can really commit any blunders, since none of these groups will have child groups, so any blunder would be limited to that caterogy?. My biggest fear was the asset table, since that can harm a lot more!

Comment: You can just take backup of that table and if anything goes wrong during execution you can retrieve it.

Comment: Ok, again though to be clear, I will not have to change the asset table, only change the category table, correct?